# How to initiate global variable after log out?

Tags: spring, session, gradle, global-variables, logout

My project actual using spring + gradle system, 
in some controller file, I added some global variable like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/question")
public class QuestionAdminController {

List<Question> questions;
String message;
Company company;
```

this is my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable(); // temporary disabled for testing file upload
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable(); // disabled for h2 console
    // Roles permissions        
    http.authorizeRequests()
            // Directories access permissions
            .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
            .antMatchers("/company/**").access("hasRole('COMPANY')")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('DBA')")
            // All user can access to new routes at the root
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            // Other requests need the login
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            // Configure the login page
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(customSuccessHandler).permitAll()
            // Default logout from Spring Security
            .and().logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?expired");
}
```

Now when I logging with another user, these global variables keep still the same value.

So I want to know: **How can I initiate these global variable after log out?**

Answer (score 0):

A controller is not the best place to initialize and store conversational state or user specific data. A Controller by default has a singleton scope hence its shared by all threads servicing user requests.

You need to extract the user specific data into a separate class which has a session scope in the application context. The bean is initialized every time a new user session is initiated. An example using Java config

```
public class UserData{
   List<Questions> questions;
   String message;
  // etc
}
     //in your @Configuration class

        @Bean
        @Scope("session")
        @ScopedProxy
        public UserData userData(){
           //initialize and return user data
        }

In your controller inject UserData as follows

    @Controller
        @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/question")
        public class QuestionAdminController {

           @Autowired
           private UserData userData;
        }
```

NB.Your UserData bean needs to be a scoped proxy because the controller into which its injected has a longer scope.Hence the proxy has the responsibility of looking up the bean from the session or creating it if it does not exist

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to use your solution, but it doesn't work, the error is "Error creating bean with name 'adminData': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton;"

Comment: I tried also 
@Scope(value="session",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)

Comment: But it keeps still the same variable after log out

Answer (score 0):

If you declare UserData a session scoped, then the @PostConstruct & @PreDestroy annotated methods will be executed when the session is created or destroyed. There you can manipulate global pareameters.

Might not be the best design however, but I need more details about what you want to achieve.